# Change TextView from Dialog EditText

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

So i have a dialog that shows up in the fragment. i need to change a textview with a dialog. 
so i created a dialog with an editText, but i am not sure how do i pass the char sequence 
from dialog to fragment.

`rename_dialog_edit` is EditText from dialog

`GroupName` is TextView from fragment

on positive click:

`GroupName.setText((CharSequence) rename_dialog_edit);`

after positive click my textview gets empty. how do i properly set it?

**Update**

```
    protected static TextView GroupName;
protected static EditText rename_dialog_edit;
```

In the onCreateView i have:

```
TextView GroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_details_name); 
EditText rename_dialog_edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.groupdetails_rename);
```

here is my onCreateDialog:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        //int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_details_rename_dialog, null))
                //.setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                //.setTitle(R.string.groupDetails_rename)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               doPositiveClick();
           }
                    })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   doNegativeClick();
                               }
                        })
                        .create();
    }
```

and here is my positive click:

```
    public static void doPositiveClick() {

    GroupName.setText(rename_dialog_edit.getText().toString());

    //Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Positive click!");
}
```

Comment: Just curious why can't you just get the Text from the EditText as a string and then pass it onto setText() of TextView ? Please show more code as to how actually are you trying to accomplish this. it would be more clear then.

Comment: i tried. was getting some errors, something like  "a string cannot get an edittext char" as i remember. could you please tell me how do i get this string correctly?

Comment: Plz show the relevant part of the code where you are trying the same. Its easier to work ou a solution then.

Comment: `new string temp = rename_dialog_edit;`
Type mismatch: cannot convert from EditText to R.string.
and then i would put temp into setText

Comment: This is not how you do it. Check my answer. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the Text from the `EditText` like:

```
String str= ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.rename_dialog_edit)).getText().toString();
```

Set it to textView like:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.this_is_the_id_of_your_textview);
text.setText(str);
```

have you tried something like this?

**Update**:

Inside the button listener just do:

```
GroupName.setText(rename_dialog_edit.getText().toString())
```

Also try to be consistent with of camelCase variable names in Java. It might be a good practice.

Comment: from what you wrote, i ended up with this code:
`String str= ((EditText) rename_dialog_edit).getText().toString();
   
  TextView text = (TextView) GroupName;
  text.setText(str);`
i thought it should work, but i my app crashes after positive click:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65257571/log.txt

Comment: My dear you forgot `R.id.` ? How else would you reference your EditText whose ID you have defined in the XML file? What is GroupName again? If you need more help, you would have o show the code hat you tried else people here wont be able to hep much. :)

Comment: here is my last code:
`String str= ((EditText) rename_dialog_edit).getText().toString();
GroupName.setText(str);`

in the onCreateView i have:
`GroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_details_name);
  rename_dialog_edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.groupdetails_rename);`

so why would i use them again?

Comment: still crashing:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65257571/log1.txt
normally this has to work, there should be something else thats triggering the crash.

`protected static TextView GroupName;
 protected static EditText rename_dialog_edit;` _____ In onCreateView `GroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_details_name);
  rename_dialog_edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.groupdetails_rename);` what could go wrong?

Comment: Its something in your `ButtonHandler.handleMessage` there is a null pointer. Can you post the java class itself as each time the sniplet you are giving is insufficient

Comment: Just curious why is `doPositiveClick` a `static` function ?

Comment: it asked me to; here is what it says if its not static:

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method doPositiveClick() from the type GroupDetailsFragment`

Comment: any other suggestions please?